# ReactJS 'navigate' of undefined inside the function to redirect to another screen

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

I got this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined, js engine: hermes
```

I am trying to redirect my code once the user logged in by pressing the button with the function.

```
 <Button  style={styles.button} title="Login" onPress={loginWithFirebase} />
```

here is my `loginWithFirebase` funtion

```
  loginWithFirebase = ({navigation}) => {
    console.log(loginEmail);
    console.log(loginPassword);
    if(loginEmail.length < 4){
      Alert.alert("Please enter a valid email address");
      return;
    }
    if(loginPassword.length <4){
      Alert.alert("Please enter a valid password");
      return;
    }
  
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, loginEmail, loginPassword)
    .then(() => {Alert.alert('User has logged in')
          setLoggedIn(true);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      if(errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password'){
        Alert.alert('Wrong Password')
      }
      else{
        Alert.alert(errorMessage);
        console.log(errorMessage);
      }
    })
    console.log(loggedIn);
    if(loggedIn){
      navigation.navigate('Login'); // this is where the error
    }
    
  }
```

my problem is how can I redirect to the Login Screen when I finished logged In the user? I am trying to use `navigation.navigate('Login')` but got an issue. anyone has an idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `loginWithFirebase` function receives an object containing a `navigation` key, but you are not passing this to the function.

Instead the function will be called by the event handler, and therefore it will receive the event for that action (click), which will not contain `navigation`.

You should pass the `navigation` to your callback yourself, e.g.

```
<Button  style={styles.button} title="Login" onPress={() => loginWithFirebase({navigation})} />
```

It's unnecessary to create and destructure an object here however, so you'd be better off just passing the `navigation` in as the only argument e.g.

```
loginWithFirebase = (navigation) => {
// etc

<Button  style={styles.button} title="Login" onPress={() => loginWithFirebase(navigation)} />
```

Or if the `navigation` is already available in the scope of that function, just remove the destructuring part from the function definition and it'll use the `navigation` from the upper scope e.g.

```
loginWithFirebase = () => {
```